# How do I make SQLAlchemy backref work without creating an orm object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

When using SQLAlchemy backrefs, the backref attribute seems to be created when the ORM object with the relationship created for the first time. In my application this is a bit unstable because there is no guarantee this will happen before the backref is used in a query.

Is it really supposed to work like this or am I missing something?

If I have a model as set up as following (from example at https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/backref.html):

```
from sqlalchemy import Integer, ForeignKey, String, Column
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    
    addresses = relationship("Address", backref="user")

class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'address'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

If I then do this, I'll get `AttributeError: type object 'Address' has no attribute 'user'`:

```
Address.user
```

But if I create an User object first, then the Address.user attribute has been created.

```
User()
Address.user
```

I am using SQLAlchemy 1.4.9.